# Animating transparent textures in blender eevee for unity?

Tags: animation, texturing

I wanted to create a character with a body material that changes color that still has facial animation, So I followed this tutorial to make a transparent texture:  duplicate mesh of the face, unwrap it, set up the nodes, then parent the mesh to the original body: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=6ExiMqTk5mw&t=87s

however, when I tried to follow this tutorial using method 1, multiple different textures:https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=nmzAbeUDPUQ&t=25s
I cannot get past even one mixrgb shader(in blender 3.30 I only see mixrgb when I go into the color dropdown to add nodes)

when I place the two transparent textures in the mixrgb the  texture  connected to color1 simply turns black.  I have one open eye texture with color and one closed eye texture that is completely black.

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

is there any other technique for animating multiple transparent image textures in a single material, or animating multiple materials?

Comment: These nodes should make the sad eye texture show, but only in the areas where the closed eye texture is opaque. The wrong blend setting could be messing this up, but I have no idea why everything is glowing cyan here.

Comment: @TheLabCat    I  set the body material for the body mesh underneath to be cyan, sorry for not mentioning!  I don't have any opaque parts, both are transparent textures. Will this technique not work? should I share the .blend file?

Comment: Read my comment again… I said “where the closed eye texture is opaque.” Also, this looks like it should do something it’s not doing (which isn’t the desired effect anyway, but you’re not far off: Yes, this type of texture switching should definitely work), so maybe yea share the file. https://blend-exchange.com